# Visual Studio debugging save point?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on a long program which needs too much time (about 1 hour execution) ...
I have already built around half of it and it was okay ... and I want to debugg my second half which needs the results of the first half, so my question is: can I save my execution status after the first half and begin execution and debugging from the beggining of the first half every time ?
cuz if I want to debug the second half I would need the results of the first half which need about 45 min to be ready every time ... and you know debugging needs a lot of retrying in such a program ...
thanks in advance ...

Comment: No, you cannot rely on VS to do this. However, you can save the first half data to disk and then load back when running for the second half.

Comment: which program could do that for me ? (c++)
it is hard to save it cuz they are too huge and consists of so much types of data

Comment: You have to design it yourself, different for different data.